# Nav drawer fragment being re-created on selection, resulting in repeated image downloads

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

My app currently has a **Navigation Drawer** with a few fragments. The default fragment which loads initially is a profile page which downloads an image (Bitmap) from a server.

When I navigate to another fragment and come back to the Profile fragment, the fragment is re-created and the image has to re-download from the server.

Is there any way to save the state of the Profile Fragment so that I don't have to keep sending a request to the server to re-download the image. Currently the UI feels very clunky due to this repeated download request that needs to be made.

Here is an extract of the code for the Activity which starts the relevant fragment.

```
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;


    switch(position+1) {
        case 1:
            Bundle LoginDetails = getIntent().getExtras();
            String [] login_info = LoginDetails.getStringArray("login_details");
            String username = login_info[0];
            String password = login_info[1];

            fragment = new Profile().newInstance(position + 1, username, password);

            break;

        case 2:
            fragment = new Search().newInstance(position+1);
            break;

        case 3:
            fragment = new NewsFeed().newInstance(position+1);
            break;


        default:
            Log.w(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Reached default on Navigation Drawer select item");
            break;
    }

    //fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentManager = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentManager.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
        fragmentManager.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentManager.commit();
    }

    else {
        Log.e("Activity", "Error Creating fragment");

    }
}
```

My **Profile.java** file (Fragment) subsequently uses an **AsyncTask** call in **onCreateView** to download the Profile Image. Should I be making this call somewhere else or is there some other way to maintain the state of the Fragment's layout?

Comment: You can try using fragmentManager.add in stead of replace. That will keep your fragment in the backstack but that also might cause undesired results. You should maybe create a db and save the user details on the device after the first download. You don't want to waste user data every time the app is opened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best soultion is to cache your image locally, you can do it manually, or by using some beautiful libraries such as [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Ion](https://github.com/koush/ion), then when your fragment will be recreated you will get that image from cache.

But if you don't want to use it, there is another way to store your image: you can move your `AsyncTask` that loads an image to `Activity` that uses `NavigationDrawer`, then execute your `AsyncTask`, for example, in `onCreate`, store the image in your activity, and when you will replace current fragment to `ProfileFragment` pass the image as a parameter to `newInstance` method. Then the image will be stored for your `NavigationDrawerActivity` lifecycle.

Comment: I'll try pass in the image as a parameter and see if I can get it working.